# mongodb aggregate object sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  "$match":{
    "field":{
      "a":"b",
      "c":"d"
    }
  }
}
```

When I search in this way, it finds the result, but when I search as follows, it does not find it.

```
{
  "$match":{
    "field":{
      "c":"d",
      "a":"b"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using dotted notation for each field you want to match.

Answer (score 1):

From [this official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects),

> Recursively compare key-value pairs in the order that they appear within the BSON object

So for 2 BSON objects to be regarded as "the same", the field orders need to be in the same order too.